# How can I prevent apps being killed prematurely on my Moto G 4G?

Tags: ram, motorola-moto-g, task-management

I have a Moto G 4G (XT1039, Android 4.4.4, non rooted) which aggressively kills apps, even while they are in use. Apparently one of the few Motorola 'enhacements' (read bloatware) compared to stock.

When driving, the only apps which matter to me are the app playing music and the app giving me directions, yet every 20 minutes or so, either Play Music, or Maps (or sometimes both) will get killed. I have to find a place to stop, pull over, set the apps going again (and often Maps has forgotten my previous destination) and set off again. It gets very irritating.

I have tried looking at Settings, Developer Options, Process Stats, but the apps which show as 100% running time cover only 250MB of the devices 1GB of memory, so it must be a non 100% running time background app waking up and pushing my running apps out of memory.

A similar thing happens with both Netflix and Ingress. Every time I watch a Netflix show longer than 20 minutes, when I open the app it reloads and I have to disconnect and reconnect to my Chromecast so that I can control the stream. Similarly whenever I switch to Ingress, even if I've just looked at the home screen, I find that it has been killed and it has to reload. I have already tried uninstalling all background apps I don't absolutely need, but I still have a problem.

Is there any way to configure the task killing behaviour without root access? Or prevent specific apps from being killed?